# Reading data from the text file into the array

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 50;
    final String FILENAME = "Collection.txt";

    CDOutput out = new CDOutput();
    CDInput in = new CDInput();

    int count = 0;  // Counter to keep track of number of elements in the array
    int choice = 0; // Menu choice

    String[] songArray = new String[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]; // Create array to hold song collection

    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) // Fill array with empty objects
        songArray[i] = ""; 



    // Read the data from the input file into the array  -  THIS


    // Return the count for the elements currently in the array 



}
```

My text file I am reading from looks like this (it goes Song then the Artist line by line):

```
Ode to Joy
Bach
The Sleeping Beauty
Tchaikovsky
Lullaby
Brahms
Canon
Bach
Symphony No. 5
Beethoven
The Blue Danube Waltz
Strauss
```

How do I assign each line into an array? I'm sorry if this is too easy as I am very new to Java.

Comment: Note that you for loop should be `for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++)`. Arrays are 0 base indexed.

Comment: you can refer to tutorial for reading a file, one is http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Comment: Is there any reason why you want them in an array? Arrays are pretty inflexible... would be much easier with a List. And just because of the fixed size I wouldnt use an array. Just my oppinion but I cant find a reason using an array in your case

Comment: @Ben yeah the whole objective for this project for class is to use array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 50;
final String FILENAME = "Collection.txt";

// CDOutput out = new CDOutput();
// CDInput in = new CDInput();

int count = 0; // Counter to keep track of number of elements in the
           // array
int choice = 0; // Menu choice

String[] songArray = new String[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE]; // Create array to hold
                         // song collection

BufferedReader br = null;

try
{

    String sCurrentLine;

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));
    int countA = 0;
    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
    songArray[countA] = sCurrentLine;
    countA++;
    if (countA == MAX_ARRAY_SIZE)
    {
        break;
    }
    }

}
catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    try
    {
    if (br != null)
        br.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE; i++) 
    System.out.println(songArray[i]);


}
```

Although I could not understand, usage of out and in objects.

Comment: Awesome works great. Before your code i had an  integer count = 0 that is supposed to keep track of how many objects are in the array. I am supposed to return the `count` after your suggested code, how am I to do this? @batty

Comment: return count where?? main method can not return anything..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to invent the wheel. You can use Apache [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readLines%28java.io.File%29)

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

example:

```
List<String> fileLines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("C:\test.txt"));
```

Comment: But he also shouldnt add any new dependency if not necessary.. ;)

Comment: That's very light weight dependancy.